# Intermittent java.net.UnknownHostException possibly caused by government censorship

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I have an interesting situation. My country has started to block sites from several countries, including Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Linked In, and almost all outside websites. My website has not been affected by this, at least not always, sometimes I can't access it and other times I can.

My Android application runs requests to my page to get user info etc, but sometimes it does not open and just stays on the splash screen after 3 times of opening and closing the app it suddenly runs and shows the home screen etc. My users have been affected by this.

I looked at the logcat and saw when the app stays only on the splash screen the logcat produced this `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "easy****m*.com": No address associated with hostname`

I know I don't have code included, but the thing is, it is not my code because like I said sometimes the app works other times it does not because the server can't be called too.

Is there a way to get around this? Our active users have gone down and we believe the main cause of this is because the app does not always open.

Also, I did use nslookup and look seems to be correct. I did some research, but found nothing that relates to my current situation only where people coded something wrong or miss-spelled something.

Comment: If you often have intermitten errors like that then you'll have to build some retry mechanism. If the duration of these problems is short-lived (i.e. a request several seconds later is likely to succeed), then just do it silently. If the interruption tends to take longer then catch the exception and post a message like "can't reach the server, please try again later". Can you reproduce the problem or do you only see this happen in logs collected from your users?

Comment: And last but not least: if your country starts blocking outside traffic and the majority of your users are in your country, then it might be a good idea to have your servers (or at least some servers) in your country to increase the chance of being able to reach them.

Comment: Firstly thank you for responding @JoachimSauer I can only see this problem when I look at the user logs. I appreciate the info you have given me and I will look into it the retry mechanism :) have a very good day!!!! and stay safe

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes that would be helpful but our current host does not have servers for your country and we already paid for 1 full year

Comment: This situation happened after a coup that we didn't expect :(

Comment: @JoachimSauer would it be possible for you to help me with a small issue? i will provide some of my code if you can help me as i can;t seem to get the retrofit clone() function to work

Comment: Please post this as a separate question, I don't really do individual 1:1 help on here.

Comment: Okay sure :) thx for the help btw

Comment: @JoachimSauer here is my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69382327/how-to-use-clone-retrofit-in-android-application